# Sending multiple forms data through jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two forms for which I want to send the data through jQuery Ajax call. I managed to send it successfully for one form but I am not able to send the data from both of them through the same Ajax call.

My forms are:

```
<form id="filter-group1"  method="post" name="filtergroup1">
<input type="checkbox" name="colour1" value="Value1" onclick="filterBy()" /><label>Option 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="colour2" value="Value2" onclick="filterBy()" /><label>Option 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="colour3" value="Value3" onclick="filterBy()" /><label>Option 3</label>
</form>
<form id="filter-group2" method="post" name="filtergroup2">
<input type="checkbox" name="size1" value="Value1" onclick="filterBy()" /><label>Option 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="size2" value="Value2" onclick="filterBy()" /><label>Option 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="size3" value="Value3" onclick="filterBy()" /><label>Option 3</label>
</form>
```

And the function is:

```
function filterBy() { 
    var fgroup1 = document.filtergroup1;
    var fgroup2 = document.filtergroup2;
    var dataString1 = $(fgroup1).serialize();
    var dataString2 = $(fgroup2).serialize();
    var filterdata = [];
    filterdata.push(dataString1,dataString2);
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'filter.php',
        data: filterdata,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I have this in the php file:

```
echo var_export($_POST);
```

The function works fine for one form if I replace data: with

```
data: dataString1,
```

I am trying to achieve the same result with the data from both forms but I don't want to use a different function for each form.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

jQuery's `serialize()` method concatenates your input values with an '&' symbol - therefore when you are pushing two serialized form data, you are creating an array and not concatenating the values in two forms with '&' (which is the one that will be parsed correctly). You can either: (1) concatenate the items in the array into a string with '&' or (2) use `$("#form1, #form2").serialize()` to do it:

```
function filterBy() { 
    // Construct data string
    var dataString = $("#filter-group1, #filter-group2").serialize();

    // Log in console so you can see the final serialized data sent to AJAX
    console.log(dataString);

    // Do AJAX
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'filter.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**[Edit]**: On a side note, I highly discourage using inline JavaScript. You should separate content from function. Instead, use the `.click()` function, like:

```
$("form input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    var dataString = $("#filter-group1, #filter-group2").serialize();
    // (and more...)
});
```

I also don't exactly understand the reasoning behind using two separate forms...

Comment: @Terry The two separate forms are in 2 different parts of the website, I just pasted them here like that for readability. Thank you for the tip regarding inline JavaScript, I will use it like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a function call in your `filtergroup2` form that doesn't exist.

`filterBy2()` I assume needs to be `filterBy()`

Comment: Yes, I've corrected that now, I was trying it with a second function but forgot to make the correction here.

Comment: Well, the JavaScript seems to work as expected as per this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/ny6nQ/. What are the results of `print_r($_POST['data']);` in your PHP file?

Comment: The results are: array (
  'undefined' => 'undefined',
)