# How to pass an array of "FormData" via ajax and access in Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

# I just want to know how to send this array the controller by requete ajax

```
var dataPanier=[];

function addarray(objser)
{
 dataPanier.push(objser);

}


$('.target').click(function() {

  var btn_name=$(this).attr("name");

     switch(btn_name) {

       case 'FormPVC':

       var dataformPVC = new FormData(),
           form_data = $('#'+btn_name).serializeArray();

          $.each(form_data, function (key, input) {
              dataformPVC.append(input.name, input.value);
           });
          dataformPVC.append('Fichier', $('#File_PVC')[0].files[0]);
/* function addarray push dataform in array*/
           addarray(dataformPVC);
break;
.
.
.
more . . .
```

I am attempting to send multiple forms data as an array by ajax to a Larave controller.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'lsitedevis',
    data: array ,
    success: function(data) {
        toastr.success('Successfully added Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});

    }
});
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208699/sending-multiple-forms-data-through-jquery-ajax

Comment: yes I saw, but I don't know how many data to add to the table,  more I used the formdata()

Comment: You have multiple forms on the same page, and you want to submit every forms data in a single request?

Comment: yes , I have more forms that contain the input type " file " ,and I want to push this data type formdata() to array in order to send a single request .

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#btnTest").click(function(){
var formData = $('#frm1, #frm2').serialize();
console.log(formData);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'lsitedevis',
    data: formData ,
    success: function(data) {
     toastr.success('Successfully added Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
    }
    
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm1">
<input name="n1" type="text"/>
<input name="n2" type="hidden" value="test2"/>
<input name="n3" type="hidden" value="test3"/>

</form>

<form id="frm2">
<input name="n1" type="text" />
<input name="n2" type="hidden" value="test2"/>
<input name="n3" type="hidden" value="test3"/>

</form>

<input type="button" id="btnTest" value="send"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your already using jQuery for the AJAX request, you could use the `serialize()` function. This supports multiple form elements, so it is possible to do:

```
var formData = $('#form1, #form2').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'lsitedevis',
    data: formData ,
    success: function(data) {
        toastr.success('Successfully added Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
    }
});
```

You might want to ask yourself why you have multiple forms but submitting them all as a single request. If it's for visual purposes, it might be easier to have a single form and separate the contents using other markup elements such as a `<fieldset>` or `<div>`.